# Continuous Bayes' Theorem and when it applies

Tags: probability-theory

So I'm still learning about when to use Bayes' theorem, and one thing I've noticed in the statement is the requirement that the data for $x$ be discrete. [image]

My question is does the theorem still apply when $x$ isn't assumed to be discrete. In other words can we still apply it for continuous data x. An example of where I would want to use Bayes' theorem is to find the density of $f(\theta\mid x\geq 1)$.

Comment: It's Bayes' (as in the quoted document, after Thomas Bayes), not Baye's.

Comment: Fixed the name.

Comment: Refixed - the apostrophe makes it possessive.